# iOS: How to use a segue in a ViewController of a PageViewController

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to I am trying to get from a UIViewController of a PageViewController to antother UIViewController via a button and a modal segue. But this isn't really working. When I'm clicking on the button I stay on the UIViewController of the page view.
I'm trying this with storyboarding.

Please find my code here:
https://github.com/LilK3ks/pageViewController

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add self.addChildViewController(vc)  and vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self) function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Change your segue from Modal to Show. Modal is deprecated as shown in storyboard. And for some reason I could not click the button i deleted and added it back again. Hope that helps